# How can I retrieve a worksheet by checking for a name in an array using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, import, phpexcel

I am working on creating an upload function for Excel Sheets in PHP using the extension PHPExcel. I have an array called `standard`, in which all allowed sheet names within an Excel document are saved. I need to loop through this array using a foreach loop and retrieve a sheet, should one of the worksheets be named the same as an entry in the array `standard`.

I have implemented it as follows:

```
foreach (array_keys($this->standard) as $k => $klasse) {
$sheet  = $this->xlsx->getSheetByName($klasse);
die($klasse.' - '.print_r($sheet,true));
```

The `die` at the end is to check if the process even returns any data. Unfortunately, I do not get any sheet returned, only the variable `klasse`. I am assuming this is due to the wrong use of the function `getSheetByName` from PHPExcel. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you expect the `foreach` will be continued after `die`? It will not. So if the first `$klasse` does not exists as sheet name, the `$sheet` will be NULL and then the script dies.

Comment: Good point - Unfortunately, if I remove the die command, I still get an error message that the sheet is null when I try to use the sheet in future code. the foreach loop is not writing the data into the sheet.

Comment: After `$sheet = $this->xlsx->getSheetByName($klasse);` `$sheet` will be NULL if there is not a sheet named `$klasse`. So you need to check whether `$sheet` is NULL and only if it is **not** NULL you can further working with that `$sheet`.

Comment: There definitely is a sheet named klasse, it is just not being written.